# Would VPS be enough for me?

Tags: heroku, hosting, vps, appharbor, vds

I have 3 ASP.NET web sites  and 3 Ruby on Rails ones. I'm planning them to be hosted on a VPS hosting. Suppouse each of them would have the attendance of 1 thousand people per day.

Now I'm hesitating about the VPS hosting. Can I host them (ASP.NET web sites  and 3 Ruby on Rails ones) side by side? Or should I use and buy 2 different   hosting: first one is for ASP.NET web sites and second one for RoR web sites?

How much power of VPS do I choose to host them? And how much  does it cost approximately?

I'm planning to pay not more than 25$ per month. If I use heroku and appharbor would they host all of them (3 and 3) and how much would it cost?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, so you can probably better off asking it at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

I think with that money you can have 2 Amazon EC2 instances, and should be fine to run those apps, plus you can have one for free for the first year.

But with heroku and appharbor maybe you can have it almost for free. Both (not sure about appharbor) gives you 1 instance free for each app, and so that should be just fine for your apps. You should just have to pay for DB, if you need to, and other add-ons that in EC2 you can have for free, but will spend some memory.

So you must put everything on the table about your apps since PaaS are not normal hosting, the cost depends on what your app needs. So you bust see if your app needs caching service, DB size and wich one, background process? ...

Comment: How many web sites that have the attendance of 1 thousand people per day can be hosted with one intance on Amazon EC2 and on  heroku?

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, well, it's up to how many requests/sec you need, and that can me improved by enabling caching on your application and other ways. So by reducing the response time of your app you should be able to respond to more requests. On heroku you can have one instance per app for free. At EC2 I think your problem should be the memory needed for those apps + database(if you need to host one).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that 1 VPS instance should be sufficient for handling 5 to 6 websites with 1000 visitors a day on each. Regarding the power, 1 GB RAM or 2 GB RAM windows VPS should be sufficient for these sites.

I know Windows VPS can handle ASP.Net websites, but I am not sure about Ruby on Rails.

I have never heard about "heroku and appharbor", so, no suggestions for them.